# How to convert AvlTree to array and vice verse?

Tags: c++, arrays, avl-tree

Lets say I have an AvlTree of some type which consists of two variables, like so:

```
class type {
    int variable1;
    int variable2;
};
```

And lets say "type" has all necessary operators so that my tree is sorted by variable2.
I want to go over my tree and update by subtracting k from variable2 from certain branches of my tree(NOT ALL OF THEM). And I need to do that in O(n) (n = size of the tree). What I want to do is to convert the tree to array of "type" update what's needed and convert back. But how?

Answer (score 0):

Why not traverse the tree "in-order" and save the output data to an array? Reading can be done in the reversed way. Should not be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do.

1. Do in-order traversal and copy the entire tree into an array.
2. Update the array.
3. Sort the array.
4. Do in-order traversal on the same tree and copy the elements from the array.
5. Free any memory if required.

Time = `O(n) + O(n) + O(nlogn) + O(n) = O(nlogn)`

If very few elements in the array are updated, do insertion sort which gives the running time as `O(n)`.